# Java get Object attribute by position

Tags: java, object, attributes

I have a list of Objects:  List< Object>. Is there a way to get the attributes by position? I was thinking at something like:

```
 for(int i=0 ; i<list.size() ; i++) {
   Object o = list.get(i);
   attribute1 = o.get(1);
 }
```

Comment: Simple answer `NO`.Whats wrong in calling `getters` when your have object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using reflection:

```
Object obj = ...
Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
```

Note that the fields order is not guaranteed, you may want to use [getDeclaredField(String fieldName)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29)

Javadoc : [#getDeclaredFields()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29)

Reflection tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

If you use `getDeclaredFields()` as some are suggesting, there is no specific order defined on the fields. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29):

> The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order.

It may be that for your use case, positional access for an arbitrary ordering works. If so, great. Otherwise use caution. You might need to impose your own order (e.g. sort the fields alphabetically after calling `getDeclaredFields()`).